# Show local video stream in HTML5 video tag

Tags: browser, video-streaming, html5-video, chromium

I working on a system where we want to show a video stream from a Video Capture card in a browser. The browser connect towards a remote server and fetch a html page that have video in it. This video should be streamed from the client machine where a video capture card is connected.

On client side we running Linux and the capture card is registered as /dev/video0 by Video4Linux2. The browser on client side is Chrome (chromium-browser). On client side we have a webserver (lighttpd) that is possible to use for streaming.

I have looked into the getUserMedia API but it seems to be poor support for that right now. Other toughts that I have had is to use the local webserver or setup a streaming server on client side that stream video source locally.

Any ideas how to design this would be great input for me!

Thanks,
/Peter

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome does not yet support RT(S)P streaming for the `<video>` tag you will have to use a plugin for this.

Given it's availability I would suggest using Flash to write simple SWF which finds the correct video source and displays.

If needed you can use one of the many 'Recording Apps' available and strip out the recording part.